# Simultaneous Search and Sort in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a simple search and sort mechanism for a test blog application.

Each function in isolation works correctly yet I'm having trouble piecing the two together.

I just want a user to be able to have the ability to search for a blog title, while also having the ability to sort by blog likes.  I likely will add future filtering capabilities at some point, so I want to make sure I set this up the right way.

I've tried multiple ways to piece the two together in my Blogs component (where I'm listing the blogs) but without any luck.

Here is my search function which takes a search term (variable 'search') and the current 'blogs' state, along with my filter function which is just sorting based on blog likes.

```
const searchBlogs = ({ blogs, search }) => {
  return search
    ? blogs.filter(a => a.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    : blogs;
};


const filterBlogs = ({ blogs, filter }) => {
  if (filter === "DESC") {
    return blogs.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes);
  } else {
    return blogs.sort((a, b) => a.likes - b.likes);
  }
};
```

I'm storing the update state of blogs after search in mapstatetoprops like so:

```
blogsToShow: searchBlogs(state)
```

And then mapping over `blogsToShow` in my Blogs component

```
const Blogs = ({ blogsToShow }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {blogsToShow.map(blog => (
        <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} user={blog.user} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

I tried to call the filterBlogs function within the searchBlogs function like this but that got really messy and didn't work, leading to some infinite looping issues.

```
const searchBlogs = ({ blogs, search, filter }) => {
  filterBlogs(blogs, filter)
  return search
    ? blogs.filter(a => a.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    : blogs;
};
```

I know there has to be a simpler and more efficient way to do this.

Note, didn't want to post too much code on this, but here is my Search component where I am dispatching to the redux store:

```
const Search = props => {
  const handleSearch = event => {
    props.searchChange(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const handleFilter = event => {
    props.filterChange(event.target.value);
  };

  const style = {
    marginBottom: 10
  };

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      search
      <input onChange={handleSearch} />
      <select onChange={handleFilter}>
        <option value="DESC">Sort Likes Descending</option>
        <option value="ASC">Sort Likes Ascending</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    filter: state.filter,
    search: state.search
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchChange, filterChange })(Search);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i came up with something that works, but it's not very elegant.

if anyone any prettier ideas, i'm all ears.  thanks!`enter code here`

```
const Blogs = ({ blogsToShow, filter }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {filter === "DESC"
        ? blogsToShow
            .sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)
            .map(blog => <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} user={blog.user} />)
        : blogsToShow
            .sort((a, b) => a.likes - b.likes)
            .map(blog => <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} user={blog.user} />)}
    </ul>
  );
};
```